# THUCYDIDES-avoid browser closing after a test run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, thucydides

I am using Thucydides/serenity which is kind of wrapper around selenium to automate some web tests
When i run a particular test and after the test run the browser closes (which is the default behaviour)
I want to make sure browser does not close so that I can check visually few things.
What should I be doing to avoid the browser closing after the test run?

Comment: When u say browser closes, you mean browser closing code call is done by your self right? So you can comment out that and part if you don't want to close the browser.

Comment: @MrunalGosar it is not an explicit statement that I wrote in my code.It is the default behaviour of closing the browser once the test finishes with either error or success.

Comment: It could be part of SerenityRunner class - closeDrivers()

Comment: can you post a sample working code to dig through